# Trouble in knitting to pdf in R

Tags: rstudio, knitr

I have the following code which runs when the code block is executed:

```
library(boot)
data("FishMercury")
# part a 
hist(FishMercury$Mercury)
boxplot(FishMercury$Mercury)

#part b

boot.fish = numeric(10^4)
for(i in 1: 10^4)
{
  boot.fish[i] = mean(sample(FishMercury$Mercury, 10, replace = TRUE))
}
boot.fishMean = mean(boot.fish)
boot.fishSD = sd(boot.fish)

quantile(boot.fish, .025, .0975)


#part c
FishMercury2 <- FishMercury[FishMercury < max(FishMercury)]
for (i in 1:n){boot.mean[i] <- mean(sample(FishMercury2, length(FishMercury2),replace = TRUE))}
mean(boot.mean)
sd(boot.mean)
quantile(boot.mean, prob= c(.025,.975))
```

However when I try to knit to a pdf I get the error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'boot.mean' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue??

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things missing in `#part c` of your code here, which lead to errors.

```
#part c

FishMercury2 <- FishMercury[ FishMercury < max( FishMercury)]

# first error, you use an uninitiated object n
n <- length( FishMercury2)
# second error: you are replacing elements in boot.mean, but never initiated boot.mean.
# so, for example, create one:
boot.mean <- numeric( length = n)

for (i in 1: n){
  boot.mean[i] <- mean(sample(FishMercury2, length(FishMercury2),replace = TRUE))
  }

mean(boot.mean)
sd(boot.mean)
quantile(boot.mean, prob= c(.025,.975))
```